# LAN multicast enabled or not?

Tags: objective-c, c, networking, network-programming

I am trying to write code on OSX in c (can use objective-c too if easier) to determine if multicast is enabled on the current machine (router the machine is connected to).  To do this I am trying the following steps:

1. Open a port and send data over multicast.
2. Listen for responses on all active adapters.
3. Filter out the 'loopback' adapter.
4. If no replies, multicast is likely disabled.

Being new to network programming, I don't understand how I would get a response from any active adapters by sending out random data, unless I had software installed on the machines that were listening.  Is there a certain multicast IP reserved that will always elicit a response, or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a machine has IP multicast addresses active (which is what I think you mean by "multicast is enabled"), look at the routing table and see if you find one or more IP v4 addresses in the range 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255.

Comment: The idea is to determine if the router the machine is connected to has multicasting enabled.  One idea was to open a socket to send out some data and open a socket on the same machine to listen on the same multicast address to see if it receives the message that was sent out.  Maybe there is a way to view the routing tables that will achieve the same result?

Comment: Determining if a router passes multicast datagrams between collision domains is a very different question. I don't know a way to do that in the general case. You might ask that as a new question. What I can tell you is that the router won't repeat the multicast datagram back on the segment it came from; otherwise other machines would receive two copies of the datagram. I'm sure the local IP stack handles the local delivery.

Answer (score -1):

Multicast is implemented by DHCP, which is not your local computer.  DHCP allocates addresses whihc correspond to multiple clients that are connected to that DHCP server.  When you craft a multicast message, you send it to this DHCP server, which then takes the packet, finds the clients who are mapped to that multicast address, and then send it in a special packet that routers automatically duplicate (so if you have 2 people part of the group connected to 1 router, and that router is connected to another router (called router 2), router 2 won't send two packets, it will send one, and then router 1 will send two copies to its clients.  The purpose of this is to speed up delievery time and not send duplicate data).  As far as the clients, the clients aren't "set up" to allow multicast, but rather the router sets them up, and the rest is transparent to the client.  The way you would have to find out if a client is connected to a multicast group, is to see if the DHCP server has created a multicast group, and then find the computer names from the IP addresses that are mapped to the multicast group.

By listening to all active adapters, you're not going to get anything but packets, which aren't going to tell you if its part of a multicast network, since they're going to look like every other packet (since the router will change the multicast address to YOUR ip address before you even see the packet).  That's the beauty of multicast.

Comment: IP multicast is orthogonal to DHCP.

Comment: Are you sure that multicast uses a DHCP server? I cannot find any mention of DHCP in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast. Or are you talking about ["Multicast DHCP"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958927.aspx) which seems to be a Windows thing to assign and configure multicast addresses?

Comment: IP multicast is a technique for one-to-many and many-to-many real-time communication over an IP infrastructure in a network.  Ip infastructure includes DHCP.  Without DHCP, we cannot reserve IP addresses, including multicast addresses (which are in the range of IP).  Also, without DHCP, how would we store a file mapping multicast groups to interfaces (IP addresses)?  Each router has a table, but there needs to be a network infastructure that facilitates this.  Maybe there are some that don't use DHCP, but then each router is just communicating with its neighbors to get this list.

Comment: Multicast is implemented by **IGMP.** Answer is completely incorrect. Your comment is also 100% irrelevant. It is not necessary to use DHCP for multicast. -1